# algorithm for finding the minimal polynomial of an algebraic number expressed in radicals

Tags: factoring, minimal-polynomials

I need an algorithm for computing minimal polynomials over the integers of algebraic numbers expressed in radicals that I can implement in a program. The only source I've found so far that gives a concrete algorithm rather than heuristic methods that only sometimes work is [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285164297_Effective_computation_of_the_minimal_polynomial_of_algebraic_numbers). The method given requires factoring polynomials over fields with finitely-generated algebraic extensions. I think I can see how that problem could be brute-forced in a way that would be guaranteed to terminate, but I did a search to get insight into a more efficient approach. The one Wikipedia gives - [Trager's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Factoring_over_algebraic_extensions_(Trager%27s_method)) - seems to require finding exactly the kinds of minimal polynomials I'm trying to find in the first place. Does that mean that users of Trager's method use a different method for finding the minimal polynomials than the one I found? Is there a method that is better than brute force that would be compatible with the method for finding minimal polynomials I found?

As per commenter hardmath's suggestion, an example of the kind of number whose minimal polynomial I'm trying to find: $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt{5}\sqrt[5]{5-\sqrt{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{10}$$ Basically, any expression that consists of a finite, grammatical combination of integers, +, -, *, parentheses, and rational exponentiations.

Comment: It would improve your Question to give an illustration of the sort of algebraic number "expressed in radicals" that interests you.   One approach is to construct an integer polynomial with the given root and then try to factor it or show it's irreducible.

Comment: Suppose you had an algorithm to find minimal polynomials of finite precision approximations of complex numbers. Would that help you?

Comment: @hardmath How might you go about constructing such a polynomial? The paper I linked takes an approach something like that, starting with a component of the expression one already knows the minimal polynomial for, and finding a minimal polynomial for a larger component using a field extended by the smaller component. The trouble is that it requires the factorization attempt to happen over the extension field.

Comment: @Somos The program I'm writing is only for giving exact answers. In theory there might be a way to make use of an approximate method along the way, but there'd have to be some trick to it for getting an exact answer out in the end.

Comment: @AlexKindel: Of course, just use high enough precision to be sure of correct results, and you can use candidate minimal polynomials and apply them to the radical expression.

Comment: That paper walks one through some simplified cases and presents examples of the various stages.  Typical is what to do about a minimal polynomial for $\alpha + \beta$ where both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known to be algebraic numbers.  If $\alpha$ has degree $m$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\beta$ has degree $n$, then in the worst case (which may well happen) the minimal polynomial for $\alpha + \beta$ will be degree $mn$.  It is possible to automate the discovery of the minimal polynomial by looking for linear dependencies among the powers of $\alpha + \beta$.

Comment: It might seem that this search takes place "in the extension field" where those powers exist, but we can avoid this by working with matrix representations, so that only rational arithmetic is required.

Comment: @hardmath I think I may have had a misconception about what the bullet point "Factor F(x) in the ring k[x]" on page 3 entails.

Comment: Briefly, the author says (at the top of page 3): "In this paper, $k$ is a commutative field of characteristic $0$. The elements of $k$
will be mentioned as the rational numbers. $k[x]$ is the algebra of polynomials with coefficients in $k$...".  The wording is a little uneven (probably a result of translation from Italian), but the author is inviting us to think in terms of $k=\mathbb{Q}$ as the base field.